# What is amount of current required for p-mosfet when load is not applied?

Tags: mosfet, current

I am using p-channel MOSFET(NTR4502PT1G) in my application in the configuration shown in the image. If 9 V input is absent, p-channel MOSFET (NTR4502PT1G) turns on, and battery power is supplied to entire system if on/off button is switched on.

I would like to know the amount of current drawn from the battery when on/off button is turned off, the 9V input is not connected to gate terminal of MOSFET and battery is connected to the source terminal.

Please help me in this regard. [image]

Comment: Your schematic makes no sense, do you have GND there or another battery or the same battery, and why do you have it at the source?

Comment: your diagram already has the switch in the power path, presumably.  there is no reason really to even use a mosfet in this situation (the normal reason would be to reduce current through the switch by controlling the gate voltage with the switch, and also the current through the MOSFET/Load, the load being between the drain and the positive supply, and the source being at ground).

Answer (score 1):

Your schematic is very confusing, because you have the source grounded, not connected to any battery.

However, the answer to your question is none at all. The gate is effectively an open circuit at all times, so if the drain is open-circuited by the switch, there's no way any current can flow through the MOSFET.